# Heroku and Cloudfront cache issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

My heroku application resizes images as thumbnails: these thumbnails are supposed to be stored by Cloudfront.
Requesting the thumb to Heroku will cause a image to be generated, which takes time, and should only be done once for each image.

Our application always access these images through Cloudfront: so the images should be generated once, then they'd be stored by Cloudfront which would serve us as long as the cache would be deemed valid.

We receive mails everytime a thumb is generated. The problem is, when we try to access those thumbs, our Heroku server is asked to generate the thumbnail again: only then the thumb is properly cached, and we can freely access it without any traffic being sent to our server.

Does anyone know why such a thing would happen ?

Comment: It seems when I use a proxy from another continent, the thumb is generated *once* *again*. Might it be that the image is only stored at one point in the world, and if a request ends up on another one of Cloudfront's endpoint, then that endpoing will make its own request, and store its own cached response ?

Comment: Afaik, each edge location is independant

Comment: Something like http://www.imgix.com/ might be super useful.